# WinForm with WebBrowser control pops Windows Security for Authentication

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, windows-security

I have created (using C#, VS2017, windows10 latest updates) a simple Windows Form application and included a webBrowser control redirecting to a page.

I am having the Windows Security pop up asking for password and I want to disable it :

- I want this application to work without human interaction
- The authentication through this pop up is not working
- It blocks further page loading and other application procedures.

Here is a screenshot : 
[image]

How can I stop this from appearing ?
Is it poping from my windows or from the application it self ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13598/Extended-NET-WebBrowser-Control) approach?

Comment: I just did, and still has the same behavior.

Comment: If you visit the URL using the standard Internet Explorer manually, do you get the same pop-up ? If yes, then it means the the application at the URL is configured to ask for credentials.

Comment: It happens on Edge (I do not have IE), but on other OSs (Linux) with firefox it does not. The page does indeed need authentication, but it asks inside the page itself.

Comment: I suspect that something like smarscreen (or probably some new thing on win OS 10) identifies that this page asks for login and does this pop up. The issue also includes that for some reason it stops the page load, and the application's execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/windows-security-popup-asking-me-to-enter-my-login/530deb46-0962-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5), here is how to solve the problem (for future questionnaires) :

1. Open Edge
2. Select the "..." and then open to Internet Explorer
3. From Internet Explorer go : tools("gear")->Internet Options->Security
4. Then select custom level
5. From the settings deselect "logon in Intranet" and select "Anonymous logon"

Why that happened :

Probably it detects "saml.company"and considers it as intranet.
Both WebBrowser control and the Edge, seem to inherit setting from Internet Explorer. And that seems to be the reason that causes that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` property which allows you to suppress script messages.

Also try to running Visual Studio 2017 in Administrator mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems to be totally different case.